# Error handling of "Acronym not defined" in acro package

Tags: errors, acronyms, acro

I have long document (900+ pages) with 500+ acronym references.

I use `acro` package I am happy with... until it has to handle errors. Once `acro` finds an acronym he's not aware of (often mispelled), it just generates an error that stops the compilation. After 30 minutes and 800 pages already compiled it's frustrating. What am I missing ?

I'm looking for advice on strategies to handle these errors (like, put them in the log) without stopping the compilation ?

MWE

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage{acro} 

\DeclareAcronym{prems}{% 
    short=asset, 
    long= underlying asset, 
}

\DeclareAcronym{deuz}{% 
    short=asset class, 
    long=asset class, 
} 

\DeclareAcronym{troiz}{% 
    short=ASJ, 
    long=actif sous-jacent, 
} 


\begin{document} 

This is the demonstration of the usage of \ac{prem} (mispelling, it should be 'prems')---which is not to be confused with \ac{deuz} or \ac{troiz}. 

\printacronyms 

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could redirect the message, but then acro fails later in the code. Imho this is only possible to resolve sanely by the package author. So make a feature

Comment: Merci @UlrikeFischer, you confirm my initial thought. GitHub feature request to follow  :)

Comment: [feature request](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/224) added on [acro Git](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro)

Comment: hm, I personally find it always much nicer when such a feature request is self contained. I don't like to have to follow links to understand what it is about.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Updated :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer FYI update in the next release [here](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/224)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with `acro` v3.6 you can do

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{prems}{
    short=asset, 
    long= underlying asset
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_acronym_undefined:n #1
  { \textbf {!#1} \PackageWarning {acro} {`#1' ~ undefined} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ac{prems}

\ac{prem}

\end{document}
```

and get warnings in the log

```
Package acro Warning: `prem' undefined on input line 18.
```

and the document

[image]

but no errors.

Comment: merci ! May I ask if the loading of big (~500) acronyms will be faster?

Comment: @JeT I do have plans but this will take a while because the necessary changes to `acro` are quite significant